# How to run a script every time a new chrome window is created?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension. How can I check if a new **window** (not a new tab) has been created in chrome, and run a script only in this case?

I currently have this in the background script, which is not working as I'd like. It only prompts the user on the first window opened.

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(askGoal());

function askGoal(){
    goal = prompt("A?");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`askGoal` function is called the first time a windows is created because you are calling your function in your add listener. You can simply:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(askGoal);
```